# MulterError: Unexpected field in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am getting MulterError: Unexpected field when I upload the files from Frontend. In the backend it is a working file but when I submit the form from the frontend it is giving me a MuterError of Unexpected file. I  am using the object of form-data because FormData of js not giving me anything in the console In my formData Object it is printing files but got MuterError from the backend. Please help to resolve this issue on the frontend side. I am using react-dropzone to upload the files. I am using Reactjs and Vite on for forntend and nodejs, MongoDB, multer for backend I ma using latest stable version of nodejs

upload.js

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = {
  upload,
};
```

s3Upload.js

```
const {
  S3Client,
  PutObjectCommand,
  DeleteObjectCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const bucketName = process.env.BUCKETNAME;
const region = process.env.REGION;
const accessKeyId = process.env.ACCESSKEYID;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY;

const s3client = new S3Client({
  region,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
  },
});

exports.s3Upload = async (files) => {
  const uploadedFiles = [];

  for (const file of files) {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: `${uuidv4()}-${file.originalname}`,
      Body: file.buffer,
    };

    await s3client.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
    const fileUrl = `https://${bucketName}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${params.Key}`;
    uploadedFiles.push({
      url: fileUrl,
    });
  }

  return uploadedFiles;
};

exports.deleteFileFromS3 = async (fileUrl) => {
  const fileName = fileUrl.split("/").pop();
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName,
  };

  await s3client.send(new DeleteObjectCommand(params));
};
```

vehicleRequest.js

```
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middleware/catchAsyncErrors");
const VehicleModel = require("../models/Vehicle");
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/ErrorHandler");
const { s3Upload, deleteFileFromS3 } = require("../utils/s3Upload")

const addVehicle = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  res.status(200).json("File")
  
}
```

route.js

```
const vehicleFilesUpload = upload.fields([
  { name: "rcCards" },
  { name: "insuranceFiles" },
]);
router.post("/addVehicleRequest", vehicleFilesUpload, addVehicle);
```

useMultipleDropzone.js

```
 import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

const useMultipleDropzone = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
 

  const handleDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    if (acceptedFiles?.length) {
      setFiles((previousFiles) => [
        ...previousFiles,
        ...acceptedFiles.map((file) =>
          Object.assign(file, {
            // name: file.name,
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
          })
        ),
      ]);
    }
  }, []);

  const dropzone = useDropzone({ onDrop: handleDrop });

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      files.forEach((file) => URL.revokeObjectURL(file.preview));
    };
  }, [files]);

  const handleRemoveFile = useCallback(
    (name) => {
      setFiles((previousFiles) =>
        previousFiles.filter((file) => file.name !== name)
      );
      
    },
    []
  );

  return { files, dropzone, handleRemoveFile, setFiles };
};

export default useMultipleDropzone;
```

FileUpload.js

```
const FileUpload = ({ name, dropzone }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        {...dropzone.getRootProps()}
        className="relative shadow h-36 w-[240px] cursor-pointer border-[1px] rounded-lg border-gray-400 justify-center items-center"
      >
        <input
          {...dropzone.getInputProps()}
          className="cursor-pointer z-2 w-full h-full opacity-0"
        />
        <div className="z-1 absolute inset-0 w-full h-full rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
          <p className="text-gray-700 font-medium text-center">
            Drop File Here <br /> Or
          </p>
          <button className="bg-[#FF5733] text-white px-4 py-2 text-sm mx-auto rounded-xl">
            Browse
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;
```

AddVehicleModal.js

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import useAddVehicleModal from "../../hooks/useAddVehicleModal";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import Input from "../inputs/Input";
import Title from "../Title";
import useMultipleDropzone from "../../hooks/useMultipleDropzone";
import ImagesModal from "./ImagesModal";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { addVehicleValidationSchema } from "../../utils/validations";
import SelectInput from "../inputs/SelectInput";
import useCountryStateCity from "../../hooks/useCountryStateCity";
import Button from "../Button";
import useRecords from "../../hooks/useRecords";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";
import { addVehicle } from "../../pages/vehicle-request/VehicleAPI";
import FileUpload from "../inputs/FileUpload";

const AddVehicleModal = () => {
  const addVehicleModal = useAddVehicleModal();
  const {
    files: rcCards,
    dropzone: rcCardDropzone,
    handleRemoveFile: handleRemoveRcCardFile,
    setFiles: setRcFiles,
  } = useMultipleDropzone();
  const {
    files: insuranceFiles,
    dropzone: insuranceDropzone,
    handleRemoveFile: handleRemoveInsuranceFile,
    setFiles: setInsuranceFiles,
  } = useMultipleDropzone();

  const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = {};
    
    formData["insuranceFiles"] = insuranceFiles;
    formData["rcCards"] = rcCards;

    console.log(formData);
    try {
      // await mutate(addVehicle(formData));
      await addVehicle(formData);
      toast.success("Success! Added new vehicle.");
      // addVehicleModal.onClose();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error("Failed to add the new vehicle.");
    }
  };

  const footer = (
    <>
      <Button type="submit" label="Submit" onClick={onSubmit} />
    </>
  );

  const bodyContent = (
    <>
      <form>
        <div className="mx-auto flex items-center justify-center mt-6 gap-4">
          <FileUpload name="rcCards" dropzone={rcCardDropzone} />
          <FileUpload name="insuranceFiles" dropzone={insuranceDropzone} />
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
  // <Input label="Email" id="Email" register={register} errors={errors} />
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        title="Vehicle Registration Form"
        isOpen={addVehicleModal.isOpen}
        onClose={addVehicleModal.onClose}
        body={bodyContent}
        footer={footer}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default AddVehicleModal;
```